# How to run script as administrator

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .NET Core 2.1 application that, when ran, should execute a PowerShell script. However, the script can only be run if PowerShell is being ran as an Administrator. Is it possible to explicitly run a PowerShell script as an Admin?

```
namespace MyApp
{
    using System.Management.Automation;

    public class Program
    {
        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.AddScript("[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(" +
                         "'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT'," +
                         "'Staging'," +
                         "'Machine')");
            ps.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @John Set an environment variable on my Elastic Beanstalk instance.

Comment: From ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Yes, because I (for some reason) can't remote into my EB instance and set it manually. So I'm trying to do it programmatically from within the API that I'm hosting on the instance.

Comment: But what benefit does this have over calling `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` in code?

Comment: None. But I can't get that to work either. lol
But either way, I'd still like to know if there is a way to run a PS script as Admin from .Net

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, you probably have to call that before calling `BuildWebHost`. As for PS, I have no answers I'm afraid :)

Comment: Yeah, with `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`, I'm getting 'Requested registry access is not allowed.' - I assume because, again, the app isn't running as admin

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/108207/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-administrator

Answer (score 0):

You may do that by selecting properties of the script and under compatibility tab, check the box that says, *run this program as an administrator*. If you cannot see compatibility tab, other method that will work is creating a shortcut file of your script and under shortcut properties, click on advance and check box run as administrator.

Comment: This is not a question about running PowerShell as an Admin. It's about running a PowerShell script as an administrator through a published .NET application

Comment: By setting the script to always run as administrator, you don't even need to set it up in a code or whatsoever.